# Need to try and block and asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am trying to run the following code, where essentially I run an api call to see how many pages exist for results in a particular time period, run api calls in a loop to get the return from each page, and then within this loop insert each result (using a forEach function) into a mongo database, if the id of that result is greater than 0.

However, the problem I have is that the api call is asychronous, so when the insert function starts to run, i get a failure saying that the array I am trying to the run the forEach function on (nspResp.responses) is undefined.

Any way I can block the running of this forEach till after the api call has completed running. I realize that I might not have structured this data correctly, so restructuring ideas would be helpful as well.

```
function request() {
    uservoiceRequest.get({
        url: "reports/user_satisfaction_responses.json",
        data: {
            page: 1,
            start_date: "2015-01-01T00:00:00-0600",
            end_date: moment().format()
        }
    }, function (err, respData) {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        console.log(respData.pages)
        for (i = 1; i <= respData.pages; i++) {
            uservoiceRequest.get({
                url: "reports/user_satisfaction_responses.json",
                data: {
                    page: i,
                    start_date: "2015-01-01T00:00:00-0600",
                    end_date: moment().format()
                }
            }, function (err, npsResp) {
                npsResp.responses.forEach(function (e) {
                    if (e.id > 0) {
                        myCollection.insert({
                            created_at: new Date(e.created_at),
                            body: e.body,
                            score: e.score,
                            id: e.id,
                            user: {
                                type: e.user.type
                            }
                        }, function (err, dataInsert) {
                            if (err) return console.log(err);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use a callback - that's what they're for.

Comment: You should probably read a little bit about  Promise.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: These APIs are asynchronous.  You should not block them.  It is required to learn how to program with multiple asynchronous operations if you are going to write code in node.js.  No sense in avoiding it - you should just learn.  To make a number of async operations truly sequential, you can either hand code it (when one finishes, start the next one), use the Async library to sequence it for you or you Promises to sequence it for you.  My preference is the Bluebird promise library.

Comment: Please describe exactly what sequence of events you want to have happen.  You have one initial async call, then embedded in that response a `for` loop with an async call in it and embedded in each one of those a `.forEach()` loop with an async call in it.  So, you have potentially many, many async calls. Exactly how to you want them sequenced.  Describe the ideal sequence of operations, not how the code would work or how you tried to do it.

Comment: @jfriend00 - sorry about the lack of clarity. Im trying to first see how many pages  of data exist for the response within the time frame provided. Then, for each page, i want to take the data, validate that the id value is greater than zero and then insert it into a mongo database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to complete a group of operations before proceeding, I would map my async calls into an of promises and then wait on them.  For example using underscore, and q:

```
var uservoiceRequestGetPromise = q.bind(uservoiceRequest.get, uservoiceRequest)
uservoiceRequestGetPromise({
            url: "reports/user_satisfaction_responses.json",
            data: {
                page: i,
                start_date: "2015-01-01T00:00:00-0600",
                end_date: moment().format()
            }
}).then(function(npsResp){
   var myCollectionInsertPromise = q.bind(myCollection.insert, myCollection)

   return Q.all(_.map(npsResp.responses, function(e){
        return myCollectionInsertPromise({
                        created_at: new Date(e.created_at),
                        body: e.body,
                        score: e.score,
                        id: e.id,
                        user: {
                            type: e.user.type
                        }
                    }
    }))
}).finally(function(){
   console.log('done')
})
```

The example I provided is a little sloppy, but honestly I was trying to use as much of your code as possible.  You could really benefit from reducing the complexity of your example down to its root principles instead of posting your exact code - it will be easier for people to work with and follow.

That said, I think  you can convert a series of NodeJs traditional callbacks into promise methods, and then map over an array and collecting the promises and then finally using Q.all too collect the promises before proceeding.

Comment: used bluebird but same approach, this worked, thanks !